# One post on frontpage and an archive page

Tags: pagination, archives, frontpage

I'm developing a theme using the underscores starter theme and I'd like to have a frontpage with just the last post and pagination, and then a separate page, with the "archive" slug, to show all posts with pagination. Is it possible to do this programmatically (adding filters and actions in the functions.php file) without creating extra templates?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

@ialocin answered the `frontpage` part of my question. This is what I came up with for the `archives` part of my question:

```
function rewrite_init() { 
    add_rewrite_rule('archives', 'index.php?archives=yes', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_init');

function rewrite_query_vars($query_vars) {    
    $query_vars[] = 'archives'; 
    return $query_vars; 
} 
add_action('query_vars', 'rewrite_query_vars'); 

function rewrite_template_include($template){     
    if (get_query_var('archives')) {        
         $template = locate_template(array('archive.php'));
    }
    return $template; 
}
add_filter('template_include', 'rewrite_template_include');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the main query for the front/home page with `is_front_page()` and/or `is_home()`, like shown below:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse104878_alter_main_query');
function wpse104878_alter_main_query($query){

    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() || is_home() ){

        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = '1';

    }

}
```

The archive page should work, if underscore starter theme has an template for it. You can alter that separatly - similar to above function - with `is_archive()`.

Comment: Yep, the undescores theme has an archive.php file. But how do I tell the /archive page to use that file?

Comment: Select the according `page template` - for example `archives page` - on the `edit screen` or in `quick edit mode` for that page. Further reading material availabel at the codex, for example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index